# Conversion error with style definition in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on following code .. of course, the solution gets built and compiles all that but when I hit F5 or start I get following error message.

*Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Style' to object of type 'System.Windows.Style'. Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'Rectangle'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle' in markup file*

This is the code:

```
   <Style x:Key="Connector1" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style123}">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Aqua"  />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Connector1_DragThumb" TargetType="Rectangle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Style123}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests that `StaticResource Style123` on which you are basing this style does not itself have `TargetType="Rectangle"`.

You can only base a `Rectangle` style on another `Rectangle` style or a base class thereof (or the default by using `{StaticResource {x:Type Rectangle}}`).

Comment: Your last statement isn't true. The requirement is that the `TargerType` of the Style is equal to, or derives from the `TargetType` of the `BasedOn` Style. `Shape` would work for example

Comment: Hi Jay, thank you ... I got that and works fine. Now, I know how it works but what about User Control? how can I treat a User Control for the same purpose?

Comment: Hi Meleak, error was thrown due to the fact that style123 was used for Path e.g. <Style x:Key="Style123" TargetType="Path"> so then I created another Style which is applied to Rectangle. This solved it.